# Open an app which is not in background using FCM

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, jitsi, jitsi-meet

My project is based on jitsi meet for android. I'm planning to go with react-native and firebase. The requirement is if one person calls the other person they will receive a call screen with ringtone. How can I achieve this if the app is not running in background?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very tricky solution that you're trying to implement, especially it's working will vary a lot when it comes to deploying the application on Chinese OEM apps.

The process that you could instead follow is, Listen for FCM notifications along with that attach a payload to validate what kind of push notification is it. Based on that if it's a push notification for an incoming call, you can launch a foreground service which will allow your app to stay active and at the same time use a custom Broadcast Receiver. The Broadcast Receiver will receiver a trigger from your FCM Service and that will be used to open an activity that has your call screen UI.

Feel free to connect for a any help needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using FCM, if there's a push notification, app automatically opens even if its not in background. But i believe you need to pass url on click of push notification of which triggers Deeplinking to actually trigger that page when the app opens, so directly it would navigate to the jitsi call page.

Check this link [rn - deep link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/)

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: I need to implement call screen instead of push notification (Similar to whatsapp,viber)